# Combine different SQL into one table using SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I would like to know how to combine different SQL queries into one table.

The format should be

```
customer_no|TOTAL_DIFF_LASTPAYMENT_OPENED_dt|utilization trend| count_enquiry_recency_365|ratio_currbalance_creditlimit
```

I have two files with data (see data sample). I want to create a new table that contains the output of these PROC's.

Data sample: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k7qz6m8w0yqenn7/AAAgYcVhHxCRNhiX5ZvK0q5Aa?dl=0

```
/*  TOTAL_DIFF_LASTPAYMENT_OPENED_dt */

proc sql;  
  select customer_no, avg(TOTAL_DIFF_LASTPAYMENT_OPENED_dt)  
  from account_30_sort  
  group by  customer_no  ;  
quit;
```

---

```
/*  utilization trend */  
proc sql;  
  select customer_no, sum (cur_balance_amt /creditlimit) / avg  
 (cur_balance_amt/(creditlimit+creditlimit))  
  from account_30_sort  
  group by  customer_no;  
quit;
```

---

```
/*  count_enquiry_recency_365 */   
DATA  WORK.ENQUIRY_30;  
    SET ENQUIRY_30;  
    num_days= dt_opened -  enquiry_dt;      
RUN;   

proc sql;  
  select customer_no, sum(enq_amt)   
  from ENQUIRY_30  
  where num_days <=365  
   group by  customer_no;    
quit;
```

---

```
/*  ratio_currbalance_creditlimit */  
 proc sql;  
  select customer_no, sum( cur_balance_amt/ creditlimit)  
  from account_30  
  group by  customer_no  
  ;  
quit;
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, post sample data, desired output, etc. What's proc1, proc2 proc3 proc4? Are you trying to join these results on customer_no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to join the result on customer_no?

```
   proc sql;
    create table want as
    select t1.customer_no
          ,avg(t1.TOTAL_DIFF_LASTPAYMENT_OPENED_dt) as proc1
          ,sum(t1.cur_balance_amt /t1.creditlimit) / avg(t1.cur_balance_amt/(t1.creditlimit+t1.creditlimit)) as proc2
          ,sum(t2.enq_amt) as proc3
          ,sum(t3.cur_balance_amt/ t3.creditlimit) as proc4
    from account_30_sort t1
        ,enquiry_30(where=(dt_opened - enquiry_dt <= 365)) t2
        ,account_30 t3
    where t1.customer_no=t2.customer_no
      and t2.customer_no=t3.customer_no
    group by t1.customer_no
    ;
    quit;
```

Comment: i have two files of dataset contents different values"kindly refer to data file". I want to create a new table contains the output of these PROC's .

Comment: and doesn't this do it?

Comment: the output is generated separately. i would like them to be in one table.

Comment: have you even looked at my answer?

Comment: its seems perfect but there are some Syntax error .

Comment: Found one. Corrected my answer. If it persists, please specify what errors you are getting

Comment: ERROR: Ambiguous reference, column customer_no is in more than one table.
 NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
 78             quit;

Comment: Edited my answer. That error message is pretty self-explanatory though

Comment: can you help me to add this proc to the list ?                                                 /* max_freq_enquiry */
proc sql;
   create table Output as   
   select customer_no, enq_purpose as freqx
   from
      (select customer_no, enq_purpose, count(enq_purpose) as lettercount
       from ENQUIRY_30
       group by customer_no, enq_purpose)  
   group by customer_no
   having lettercount = max(lettercount);
quit;

Comment: Comments are for clarifying the answer, not for extending the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622323/splitting-string-variable-into-multiple-values-in-sas