# compare cell entries and return values In SAS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

just would like to compare cell entries and return values.

```
coustmer_NO  id   A1   A2   A3  A4   
1            5    10   20   45   0     
1            13   0    45   2    5  
2            4    0    10   7    8  
2            3    7    9    55   0        
2            10   0    0    0    0   
3            4    90   8    14   3             
3            10   20   7    4   15
```

how to count the ID that has (value > 030) for each customer_no
then, the min number of values before 030 appears.

The expected output would be something like:

```
cosutmer_no  ,   count_ac_num ,   values   
1                   2            1    
2                   1            1   
3                   1            3
```

Comment: This is better in a data step than SQL and using SUBSTR

Comment: i have try to do that, still facing an issue with it.

Comment: Explain the logic for the numbers you have posted. If you are counting values > 30 then why does customer 2 have a 3 when there is only one. And why does customer 3 havea 0 then it also have one value > 30 ?

Comment: That is my mistake customer 2 suppose to have 1 values before >30 appear. which is A4 . Also, look at customer 1 he have 2 values >30 but i would like to choose the min which is in the first  row A4 only. same thing for coustmer 3 .. A2, A3 and A4

Comment: Still not clear what you are doing. It sounds like you are using a two or three step process. Perhaps you could spell that out.  Looks like first you compare each A value to your cutoff of 30. Then perhaps you want the index number of the first A value that is > 30? And then you want to take the min of that over every row?

Comment: Exactly, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting to a more vertical structure. Then you can begin trying to apply your business logic, although I am having a hard time understanding what that is.

Assuming that the quotes are not meaningful (looks like someone had a string like `"xxx"` that had actual quote characters in it that was written to a CSV file and so extra quotes where added to protect the existing quotes so it became `"""xxx"""`) you could just use `compress()` function to remove them.

You could then just split the resulting string into 3 character substrings.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array h history1 history2 ;
  do history=1 to dim(h);
    h(history)=compress(h(history),'"');
    length index 8 value $3 ;
    do index=1 by 1 until (value=' ');
      value=substrn(h(history),3*(index-1)+1,3);
      if value ne ' ' then output;
    end;
  end;
  drop history1 history2;
run;
```

So you end up with something like this:

```
Obs    id    type    history    index    value

  1     1     13        1          1      STD
  2     1     13        1          2      STD
  3     1     13        1          3      058
  4     1     13        1          4      030
  5     1     13        2          1      STD
  6     1     13        2          2      030
  7     1     13        2          3      066
  8     1     13        2          4      036
  9     1     13        2          5      030
 10     1     13        2          6      STD
 11     1     13        2          7      STD
 12     1     13        2          8      STD
 13     1     13        2          9      STD
 14     1     13        2         10      STD
 15     1      3        1          1      STD
 16     1      3        1          2      STD
 17     1      3        1          3      STD
 18     1      3        1          4      XXX
 19     1      3        1          5      STD
 20     1      3        1          6      XXX
 21     1      3        1          7      S
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you so much. i have to convert it into a new format. could you please check the question again.