# count the values in one column by SQL - using SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I have a `customer_no` and `class`.
I would like to calculate ratio from the same column for each customer.

```
ratio= (number of secured/ total number classes)
```

```
customer_no        class  
1                  unsecured   
1                  secured   
1                  secured   
2                  unsecured   
2                  secured   
3                  secured   
3                  unsecured   
3                  secured   
3                  unsecured
```

The output sample will be

```
customer_no   ratio   
1              0.666 
2              0.50  
3              0.50 
.       
.   
.  
20000
```

Comment: Do not post sample data as images please, always post it as formatted text.

Comment: Sorry, i will modify that

Comment: `2 / 3 = 0.666666` ! ratio of `1` how become `0.75`?

Comment: I put the answer as sample. I have modify the question. The correct answer is 0.666

Comment: What code did you use that got 0.75 as the ratio?  Are you counting the number of observations or the number of distinct values that occur? Or do you need to count the number of distinct values that could occur? If it is that last then you need a source for the number of possible values as some values might not appear in your actual data.

Comment: @user2975180 So, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate ratio in a query like this:

```
select customer_no,
    (count(case when class = 'secured' then 1 end)     -- count if class is secured
    +0.0)                                              -- add by a double value to cast values to double to get scales
    / count(*) ratio                                   -- count of all class
from yourTable
group by customer_no;
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d6f9a/3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
   create table want as  
   select customer_no   
   ,sum(case when class='secured' then 1 else 0 end)/count(customer_no) as ratio   
   from  WORK.ENQUIRY_30   
   group by customer_no;   
quit;
```